# I'm trying to create a GUI in Python which would accept a bash command and would display everything including graphical outputs

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, pyautogui

I'm trying to create a GUI in Python which would accept a bash command like this
`python OK21.py`
and displayed all the outputs of this command **including any graphics**.

If I run from command line this
`python OK21.py`

it does so, but when trying to do it from GUI like here:

```
# import required modules
import os
import pyautogui

# prompts message on screen and gets the command
# value in val variable
value = pyautogui.prompt("Enter Shell Command")

# executes the command and returns 
# the output in stream variable
stream = os.popen(value)

# reads the output from stream variable
out = stream.read()
pyautogui.alert(out)
```

*it displays only text outputs omitting the graphics windows present*.
**EDIT** the best solution is to do it without any saving images to `png` files. But, if this could have been done automatcially, it may be a good solution for me.
Also I have `python 3.6.13` and I cannot upgrade for some reasons.

Comment: Graphical outputs do not go through the normal console interface, so there's no mechanism for Python to capture them.  You'll need to use a module that can find and do a screen capture of those graphical windows.

Comment: @MarkRansom Which module that might be ?

Comment: If I knew, I would leave an answer.  Pyautogui might have some abilities there, at least for finding a window.

Comment: @MarkRansom Such an obvious and basic thing should not be left without an easy enough solution ?

Comment: How can I do the `screen capture` like this if I do not have the window displayed yet: `import pyautogui
im1 = pyautogui.screenshot()
im1.save(r"C:/Users/Hynek/Desktop/Untitled.png")` ?